# Swagger for Jersey API using embedded Grizzly

Tags: jersey, swagger, grizzly

I'm pretty new to JAVA, and more specifically REST based services in JAVA.

I'm using Grizzly as an embedded web server, serving up a Jersey REST API. That's all working great, but when I try to add in Swagger to document the API, it doesn't work.

Here is my POM (using maven)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
         <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <groupId>swagger_test</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger_grizzly_test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <!-- bring in all the jersey dependencies we need, from the same version -->
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                    <version>2.13</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- the web server -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- json serializer -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- jersey for API documentation -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.12</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

And here is my Main function, launching the server. Note my 'Browse' resource is under the package 'resources'.

```
public class Main
    {
    public static void main(String [ ] args)
        {
        String restUrl = "http://localhost:8080";

        // Grizzly makes you add the resources you want to expose
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages ("resources", "com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing");

        HttpServer server = null;
        try
            {
            server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(URI.create (restUrl), rc);
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Started...");
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println("Failed to start (" + e.toString () + ")");
            }

        // Wait for the user to close out of the app
        try{System.in.read();} catch (IOException e) {}

        if(server != null)
            {
            server.shutdownNow ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Lastly, here is my one and only resource.

```
@Path("browse")
@Api(value = "/browse", description = "Browse tags")
public class Browse
    {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Browse for tags", notes = "Returns all tags in a flat list")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Something wrong in Server")})
    public String browse ()
        {
        return "Hello World";
        }
    }
```

If I go to http://localhost:8080/api-docs I get...

```
{
apiVersion: "1.0.0",
swaggerVersion: "1.2"
}
```

Note there are no APIs listed. I've followed a number of tutorials, but I'm not using servlets (directly) so I think this is a little different?

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: There are several solutions in our google group. I'd suggest looking there first.

Comment: Could you post a link? Which group? I've spent a few hours on this and done considerable googling.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swagger-swaggersocket - all our support information can also be found in our website - http://swagger.io

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code here https://github.com/SingleMalt/jersey2-grizzly2-swagger-demo, match it, and it should work. I got it working now.

My biggest hurdle is that I'm loading the grizzly server from a JAR file. For some reason Jersey can't find the resources (including swagger), from the package names and I need to call rc.register(Browse.class); directly for each class.

This forced me to add the following from the "com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing" package to get things working.

```
// Required to support Swagger
rc.register(JerseyApiDeclarationProvider.class);
rc.register(JerseyResourceListingProvider.class);
rc.register(ApiListingResourceJSON.class);
```

Comment: The link is dead.